# How to conver date type in hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

I have a situation. I have two kinds of date in the mysql database. One is date and another is datetime. Now in hibernate criteria I have to check whether one date is greater than the other or not?

criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("award.deadline", "submission.date_received"));

But the different types are causing problems showing "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date".

Even I tried to parse it using date parser but it is not taking as date as it is taking as string only. So, can you tell me how can we convert one date to different type inside the hibernate criteria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that `Restrictions.lt(String propertyName, Object value)` is the wrong Restriction. What you need is **`Restrictions.ltProperty(String propertyName, String otherPropertyName)`**.

Explanation:

- `Restrictions.lt(String propertyName, Object value)` is to compare a entity property with a specific Value
- `Restrictions.ltProperty(String propertyName, String otherPropertyName)` is to compare a two entity properties

If you use `Restrictions.lt("Y", "X")` and "Y" is the name of a date property, then hibernate would try to translate "X" to an Date (not to an column name), and parsing "X" to an Date is, lets say, a bit complicated - so the Exception is rised.

Comment: Thanx Ralph for your valuable answer.