# Using restriction of Criteria API in hibernate for Date

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, criteria-api

The situation is like this. The format of the date in SQL server is different from oracle. In SQL server it is stored as TimeStamp. How does Restriction.eq , Restriction.lt, Restriction.gt work on Date objects ? Is there any way to just use date and not the time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343301/how-to-conver-date-type-in-hibernate-criteria), you can use `Restriction.ltProperty` and related restrictions on date fields and Hibernate will do its best to parse them.

In case this approach should not work, you can always write your restrictions in native SQL using `Restrictions.sqlRestriction`.

Comment: For equality check, how about I use Restriction.between("dateFromDB", myDateObjSt, myDateObjEnd) ? where myDateObjSt is the date with time 0:0:0.000 and myDateObjEnd is date with time 23:59:59.999 ??

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I have a Date object and I want to compare a Date column in DB for equality with my Date object. But issue is the time is also taken into consideration. So to compare only date I am thinking of using Restriction.between("dateFromDB", myDateObjSt, myDateObjEnd). myDateObjSt and myDateObjEnd are both my Date object except for the time. myDateObjSt has 0:0:0.000 as time and myDateObjEnd has 23:59:59.999 as time.

Comment: Yeah, that would probably be the easiest option. Another way I can think of is using your databases date/time operations directly in a native `sqlRestriction`. The latter obviously makes it harder to move to a different database vendor.